# Matching Map without Recreating

Tags: c++, dictionary, key, assignment-operator

Say that I have two `map`s. The values of these `map`s are the same and are expensive to construct (not to copy). The keys of these `map`s are of different types but are convertible to each other. I need to set the contents of the first `map` to match that of the second, but I'm having to loop all the way through both `map`s. Is there a way to do this?

As an example of this I've simplified the keys to something more recognizably convertible, and just used `int`s for the values. In the example, I want to set the contents of `foo` to match the contents of `bar`. But I can't find a way to do it without looping through both `map`s.

```
map<int, int> foo = {{1, 100}, {2, 200}, {4, 400}};
map<char, int> bar = {{'1', 200}, {'3', 300}, {'5', 500}};

for(auto i = foo.begin(); i != foo.end(); ++i) {
    if(bar.end() == bar.find(static_cast<decltype(bar)::key_type>(i->first) + '0')){
        foo.erase(i);
    }
}

for(auto i = bar.begin(); i != bar.end(); ++i) {
    const decltype(foo)::key_type key = i->first - '0';

    if(foo.end() == foo.find(key) || foo[key] != i->second) {
        foo[key] = i->second;
    }
}

for(const auto i : foo){
    cout << i.first + 10 << ": " << i.second << endl;
}
```

This correctly outputs:

> 11: 200
>   13: 300
>   15: 500

[[Live Example](http://ideone.com/1GJhHV)]

Is there a way to do this that does not require looping through both `map`s?

Comment: Do the keys have the same ordering?

Comment: In that case, you could achieve the same result a little faster by looping through both maps in parallel and merging. That avoids the `bar.find()` call, but you still need to iterate both maps. I don't know a way around that.

Comment: if the keys are convertible, why do you need both?

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum This is an unfortunate artifact of the design I'm working in. In fact *I do not need both* and if I was allowed to I would remove one. However at this time I'm stuck doing the conversion, so I'd at least like to do that right.

Comment: @rici I think your answer is as good as I'm going to do. If you feel like posting, please do otherwise I can write it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to synchronize two collections without examining every element of each collection. So you are going to have to iterate over both collections.

But if the collections are keyed in the same order, you may be able to speed things up a bit by iterating over the two collections in parallel and merging. This will be particularly effective if your standard library has a useful implementation of `emplace_hint`.

The basic pseudocode (meaning that it won't compile and may not work properly :-) ).

```
/* Makes a into a copy of b, assuming that the key types are
 * consistently comparable, and that a key for a can be constructed
 * from a key for b.
 */
void merge(Map1& a, Map2& b) {
  auto it_a = a.begin(), end_a = a.end();
  auto it_b = b.begin(), end_b = b.end();
  for (;;) {
    if (it_a == end_a) {
      /* Add remaining elements from b to a */
      for (; it_b != end_b; ++it_b)
        a.emplace_hint(it_a, it_b->first, it_b->second);
      return;
    } else if (it_b == end_b) {
      /* Remove remaining elements from a */
      while (it_a != end_a)
        it_a = a.erase(it_a);
      return;
    } else if (it_b->first < it_a->first) {
      /* Insert an element from b */
      a.emplace_hint(it_a, it_b->first, it_b->second);
      ++it_b;
    } else if (it_b->first == it_a->first) {
      /* Replace an element from b */
      a->second = b->second;
      ++it_a, ++it_b;
    } else {
      /* Delete element from a */
      it_a = a.erase(it_a);
    }
  }
}
```

**Note:** The above code takes care not to unnecessarily construct a new value if it can overwrite an existing value, but it doesn't really avoid constructing values, since it might destroy a value associated with an unneeded key in `a`, and then construct a value associated with a key not present in `a`. If copy-constructing is much more expensive than assignment, then it might make sense to keep a pool of constructed values, at the cost of adding an indirection to the map values. `shared_ptr` is another possibility, although it might be overkill, too.

Comment: Because my particular problem has ordered keys for both `map`s this is the best solution for me so I'm accepting it. In the general case with access to Boost, [Barry's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32315474/2642059) may be preferred though.

Answer (score 0):

With the boost [`transformed`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/transformed.html) adaptor, you could simply use the `std::map` constructor that takes two iterators and achieve the same thing in a less error-prone, more-direct way:

```
using namespace boost::adaptors;
auto transformed_map = 
    bar | transformed([](const std::pair<const char, int>& p) {
        return std::make_pair(p.first - '0', p.second);
    });

foo = std::map<int, int>(std::begin(transformed_map),
                         std::end(transformed_map));
```

I find the above easier to understand.

Now if you find yourself doing this a lot, and the construction cost is too expensive, this may be indicative of a larger design issue. Perhaps you want to store `shared_ptr<value_type>` instead of `value_type`. Or perhaps you just want to do something like:

```
struct two_maps {
    std::map<int, int> foo;

    auto from_foo(int k) { return foo.find(k); }
    auto from_bar(char k) { return foo.find(k - '0'); }
};
```

Comment: Interesting idea. I don't have access to Boost for this though so that solution won't float me.